# How to get exact value for mongoDB double value

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have little experience with MongoDB. I am usually working on SQL DBs.
I tried to get a double value from MongoDB using c# driver.

Data ==> {"Reading":20.15}

```
Query ==> 
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Reading").Exclude("_id");
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filterDefintion = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Company","companyname");
collection.Find(filterDefintion).Sort(sortDefinition).Project(project).FirstOrDefault();
```

Result ==>
{ "Reading" : 20.149999999999999 }

how to get exact value 20.15 from MongoDB ??

Thanks for your help

Comment: How is it totally different? Can you explain how to represent 0.15 in binary?

Comment: Moreover there is a "MongoDB specific" variant of that longer and generic explanation, which basically says "Don't use **Double** for this purpose". There are other types and better ways if floating point precision is something you need.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto I don't understand why these question marked as duplicate

Comment: @NeilLunn .Is it any way to get double value with precision

Comment: @arun Go [here](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) and check "Decimal" and "Binary" under "Outputs". Then enter your 20.15 and click "Convert". You will see that 20.15 cannot be represented in binary, and thus is a repeating `.0010011` forever. Because there is limited storage space available, this eventually stops and you get the closest approximate value available. (This _is explained_ in depth in the duplicate)

Comment: If it's easier to think about: you can't precisely represent 1/3 in decimal. You have to stop at an acceptable level of precision, right? Computers are limited by their architecture.